# How to prevent paragraph text from breaking onto next line

Tags: html, css

I have a div that changes width according to parent div width. This is to create responsiveness: when screen width gets reduced, that width will also change with it.

Problem: when the screen width is reduced, the text keeps on changing, as in the words that overflow get sent onto a new line (of course this happens because the width is parent div is variable.

How can I prevent this from happening? Is it as simple as creating a fixed width parent div or are there other solutions? Thanks

CSS

```
div.parDiv {
width:80%;
margin-left:10%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parDiv">
    <p class="text">This is some long text that breaks onto the next line when reducing the screen width</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen to the text when the screen width is reduced?

Comment: If it is on two lines, I want it to stay on two lines, instead of going on 3 when screen size is reduced further

Comment: Ok, so I updated my answer to include an example where you can have a 2-line paragraph that stays on 2 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what you want to achieve exactly, but if you want the text to stop wrapping, use `white-space: nowrap`:

```css
div.parDiv {
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parDiv">
    <p class="text">This is some long text that breaks onto the next line when reducing the screen width</p>
</div>

<div class="parDiv">
    <p class="text">This is some long text that breaks onto the next line here<br/>
    because of the break element included</p>
</div>
```

I should point out that the text will overflow it's container once the width of the latter is less than the width of the text, so you might want to use a `min-width` rule to prevent that.

Comment: pay attention to overflow on small screen

Comment: @TemaniAfif - indeed. I was trying to work out the right words to use in describing the problem =)